# Why to create categories of simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, simple-product, category-products

I need to ask why do we create categories of simple products if we set that to not visible individually..?

Is there any specific purpose for it..?

Comment: These products should then be added to a grouped product or a configurable product, otherwise they won't be visible on the frontend.

Comment: and if we add category to simple products.. at what places would those "simple product with category" be used or how would they be useful..?

Comment: If you set those simple products to "Not Visible Individually", I don't think there is gonna be a difference if you assign category to them.

Answer (score 0):

The store owner may want to be able to search/sort and export products based on category.  Having them set to not visible individually as the others have pointed out is for special reasons like child products or configurable products.  The frontend will just ignore these products when showing results.